# Как оптимально разместить куб, чтобы он не пересекался с другими кубами?

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия, 3d

Есть несколько кубов лежащих рядом или друг на дружке, они лежат не ровно, и могут быть расположены как угодно (но ориентация кубов всегда по осям). Есть кубик который нам нужно разместить, в определённых координатах, или как можно ближе к ним. Я ставлю этот кубик в   нужные координаты, проверяю на пересечение с другими кубиками, и если пересечений нет ставлю кубик, но что делать если пересечения есть? Как понять куда нужно передвинуть кубик, чтобы он перестал пересекаться с другими?

Comment: а у Вас сть картинка?

Comment: картинки у меня нет

Comment: мне кажется надо сразу определить куда ставить куб при помощи какого нибудь `heatmap` плотности кубов, либо Монте-Карло, еще есть алгоритм `poisson disk sampling`, но он больше про оптимальное распределение

Comment: А каким способом задаются кубы? центром и длиной ребра или как-то по-другому?

Comment: Кубы задаются центром и длинами рёбер

Comment: R-tree не способно обслуживать подобные запросы? (свободное место указанного размера поблизости от заданной точки). Кроме того, подобные проблемы встают в 2D-задаче `Label Placement Algorithm` (правда, там обычно все прямоугольники могут сдвигаться)

Comment: Вариант найти площать пересечения между фигурами и двигать в любую сторону. Найти направление, при перемещении в которое площать пересечения падает. Но могут быть ситуации, когда он начнет пересекаться с двумя или даже тремя фигурами, а там беда

Comment: Полагаю, что ставя кубик в нужные координаты, у вас также есть какой-то параметр, отвечающий за ограничение на смещение от заданной позиции. Если да, то можно пожертвовать точностью и разбить пространство возможных позиций на дискретные точки (регулярная сетка) с каким-то шагом (точностью), в которые можно поместить центр куба. И просто перебрать все варианты (проверить кубы на пересечение довольно тривиально). Для оптимизации могут сгодиться Квадро- и октодеревья для сужения пространства перебора уже существующих кубиков.

Comment: _"но ориентация кубов всегда по осям"_ что вы тут имели ввиду?